# Laravel Vue app not returning specific page with url

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Issue with setting up 404 routes to return front end components/pages in my laravel vue app.

When I go to a specific url such as "localhost/myapp/about" it doesn't return that specific component or page. 
This is how my router is set up.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: 'about',
            name: 'about',
            component: About,
        },
    ],
});
```

I've tried adding this to my routes file in laravel but still having issues

```
Route::get('{path}', function () {
    return view('index');})->where( 'path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?' );
```

Comment: You put your compiled JS and CSS in public directory.

Comment: can u try Route::get('/{path}')

Comment: Are you missing a forward slash '/' in path: '/about'?